# Error when trying to use my own .msg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried to use my own .msg to send between nodes but I'm having some trouble. I got an answer on It before http://answers.ros.org/question/95406/how-can-i-use-my-own-msg/ but I don not get It to work properly.

The package .xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>distanceCalc</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The distanceCalc package</description>
  <maintainer email="patrik@todo.todo">patrik</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>stereo_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_generation</run_depend>
  <build_depend>msg/distanceMessage</build_depend>
  <run_depend>msg/distanceMessage</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>stereo_msgs</run_depend>
  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

The CmakeList.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(distanceCalc)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  pcl
  pcl_ros
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  stereo_msgs
  message_generation
)
 add_message_files(FILES distanceMessage.msg)

generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(distanceCalc src/distanceCalculation.cpp)
target_link_libraries(distanceCalc ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_dependencies(distanceCalc distanceCalc_gen_msg_cpp)
```

In my case I have projects within my src folder in the catkin_ws, one of them is named distanceCalc and have a folder named msg where the message distanceMessage.msg is placed.

Is there some mistake that I'm making, because when I try to inclide the message with
the line

```
#include <msg/distanceMessage>
```

in my cpp file which exists in the src folder in the project distanceCalc I get an error (when trying to perform the catkin_make command) saying

```
"fatal error: msg/distanceMessage: No such file or directory"?
```

If this is not enough information to answer the questions please inform me and I will update.

Regards, Patrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95541/error-when-trying-to-use-my-own-.msg/) by [Mr Hillgren](https://answers.ros.org/users/7066/mr-hillgren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to include the header file of the message. You should include a build command for this in you CMakelist: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Messages.2C_Services.2C_and_Action_Targets.
Then a header file is generated which you should include.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0